# How can I remove content from <style> tags using Html.fromHtml()?

Tags: android, html, spannable, htmlcleaner

I need to get "plain text" from html strings I'm using Html.fromHtml that works pretty good, but I notice that sometimes HTML has  tags and although clean the tag well, doesn't remove the content.

I think this behavior has sense, but doesn't fit my needs. Do you know how can I remove the html inside  tags? Do I have some extra string processing? (like substrings, regexp or so...).

I read about TagHandler, but I'm not sure that could solve my problem, seems something to handle additional tags not to remove content for a specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can try replace it, something like

```
replaceAll(""">([a-Z0-9]*)<""", "")
```